# How to get the Sum of Row Values from SQL Database and Display on foreach loop in Blade View in Laravel 7

Tags: sql, database, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

I have a deposit table wherein there are multiple rows display. I have a this `foreach` loop on my blade file which works totally fine and shows the values like the image

```
@foreach ($moneytradeDeposits as $mtd)
   <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-primary text-uppercase mb-1">Deposited</div>
   <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">Php {{$mtd->amount}}</div>
@endforeach
```

[image]

But I also have another blade file where in I want to display the sum or total of the values from the `amount` row. I have tried the codes

```
<div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">Php {{$mtd->amount->sum}}</div>

<div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">Php {{$mtd->amount->sum()}}</div>

<div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">Php {{$mtd->amount->getTotal()}}</div>

<div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">Php {{$mtd->amount->total()}}</div>
```

But none of these seemed to work and I only get errors. by the way, this is my `Schema` for this table

```
 Schema::create('money_trade_deposits', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->string('mt_dep_number');
       
        $table->integer('amount');
        $table->string('payment_method');

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->timestamps();


    });
```

And my Controller is

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'amount' => ['required', 'integer', 'max:2000000'],
        'payment_method' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],

    ]);

    $moneyTradeDeposit = new MoneyTradeDeposit();

    $moneyTradeDeposit->mt_dep_number = uniqid('MTDepNumber-');

    $moneyTradeDeposit->amount = $request->input('amount');
    $moneyTradeDeposit->payment_method = $request->input('payment_method');

    $moneyTradeDeposit->user_id = auth()->id();

    $moneyTradeDeposit->save();


    return redirect()->route('mt.deposit')->withMessage('Added a New Deposit');
}
```

What is the best way to achieve this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Would you please clarify more. You want to sum all `amount` inside the foreach loop and want to get all sum (total amount from each row) outside the foreach loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either use the sum method on the collection like this:

```
$moneytradeDeposits->sum('amount')
```

or use the query builder method:

```
MoneyTradeDeposit::sum('amount')
```

Answer (score 1):

If I really get your question, then you can do like this :

```
@php
   $sum = 0;
@endphp
@foreach ($moneytradeDeposits as $mtd)
   <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-primary text-uppercase mb-1">Deposited</div>
   <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">Php {{$mtd->amount}}</div>
  @php
      $sum += (float)$mtd->amount;
  @endphp
@endforeach
```

Now you can access `$sum` as total of all amount